# Setting same PDF form fields in iTextSharp on multiple pages

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, report, itext

I have a PDF template used as source for a PDF report with some fields in the header. I have to repeat the header for each report page but the fields are filled only in the first page and I don't know how to fill them on all report pages.

Here's a simplified code, I reduced the switch with fieldKeys for readability, the default has the same code.

```
using (var pdfReader = new PdfReader(templatePath))
{
    using (var pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(destinationPath.Replace(".pdf", "_1.pdf"), FileMode.OpenOrCreate)) { FormFlattening = true })
    {
        InsertTables(pdfStamper);
        InsertLastPage(pdfStamper);
        InsertFooter(pdfStamper);

        var pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

        var fieldKeys = pdfFormFields.Fields.Keys;

        foreach (var k in fieldKeys)
        {
            switch (k)
            {
            default:
                pdfFormFields.SetField(k, Convert.ToString(Request.GetType().GetProperty(k).GetValue(this, null)));
                break;
            }
        }

        pdfStamper.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the PDF template in question?

Comment: Sorry but I can't. It's half-empty with some fields created with Acrobat, first page is correctly filled but others don't.

Comment: I'm sorry, without template and result PDF this is really hard to review. That been said, do `InsertTables`, `InsertLastPage`, or `InsertFooter` add any pages with form fields? If they do, I would propose making this a two-step affair, first stamping the template using those `Insert*` methods and saving this intermediary result to memory or temp file, opening it in a `PdfReader` and stamping this reader using set field operations. The background: Most likely the stamper only sees the fields already present in the reader it stamps, not necessarily fields added by itself.

Comment: InsertTables and InsertLastPage adds again the template (w/ form fields) if tables needs more pages and for use it as header for lastpage. I tried to split Insert* methods to Field setting method in two step stamping but the problem is not solved. It continues filling only first page fields, others remains blank.